# How to structure my own MVC PHP app with dependency injection?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, php-8

Sorry if the title of the post is unclear, I will try to be as simple as possible, because I really think this question has a simple answer.

First of all I will add some code(not real code, just for testing):

Model:

```
class User{
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $age;
}
```

Interface:

```
interface IData{
   public function search(User $user)

}
```

Class Repository:

```
class DataRepository{
    protected $db;
    public $conn;
    public $data;


    // Passing the interface DB to the constructor
    public function __construct(DB $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }


    public function search(User $user){
        $query = " SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE id_user = ". $user->id . " and name = '%" . $user->name . "%'";
        $this->conn = $this->db->connection();
        $this->data = $this->conn->query($query);
        $dataList = [];

        foreach ($this->data as $row)
        {
            $dataList [] = (object)array(
                "name" => $row["name"],
                "age" => $row["age"],
            );
        }

        return $dataList;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
class UserController{
    public $Idata;


    // Passing the interface IData to the constructor
    function __construct(IData $Idata) {
        $this->Idata = $Idata;
    }


    // Function to search the user and return an array with the data
    function printData(){
        $Mdata = new User();
        $Mdata->id = 5;
        $Mdata->name = "Carl";
        $Mdata->age = 39;

        $result = $this->Idata->search($Mdata);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php


// We create an instance of UserController

$UserData = new UserController();


// Print the data
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($UserData);
echo "</pre>"

?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So I was trying to learn the repository pattern using MVC, to sepearate my DB layer from the controller and encapsulate, all was looking great, until the moment i needed to use the IData interface on the main Controller(UserController), on my view i had an error

`$UserData = new UserController() -> returns an error: Expected 1 arguments. Found 0`.

I know the meaning of this error, that it requires a parameter(interface), hovewer it feels weird to instance the interface on the view side, for later on pass it as an argument to the contructor.

I tried to:

```
<?php

$IData = new IData();

$UserData = new UserController($IData);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($UserData);
echo "</pre>"

?>
```

it returns this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface IData`.

My main question is, is there any way to use the interface only on the constructor of UserController, without having to define it on the view?

if it's not possible(for sure it will be the case), what should I do?( i can't use the keyword `implemante`, because i'am trying to use the repository pattern, making dependecy injection from the constructor)

Comment: `function __construct(IData $Idata)` - That means you need to send in an object that _implements_ the interface. Your `DataRepository`-class should implement that interface, and then you pass in the instance of `DataRepository` to your `UserController`. You should also avoid creating instances in the views. Your controller should fetch all the data the view needs and just pass the data to the views. The views shouldn't need to know where it comes from or how to fetch it.

Comment: Agreed, it is very unclear why you would be trying to instantiate a controller from a view. That's not how MVC works at all. The routing engine should instantiate the controller, with the assistance of the dependency injection system to generate suitable objects to pass in as parameters to the controller's constructor

Comment: Unrelated to current issue but `SELECT * FROM test_db WHERE id_user = ". $user->id . " and name = '%" . $user->name . "%'` is strange. 1. Values should be bound in 2. If the have the user id why do you need the name 3. Why does the name have wildcards on it, or is that typo for operator (e.g. `=` should be `like`)?

Comment: @M.Eriksson okei thanks! i will try it. I have a question, you said I should avoid using instances on the view, if i don't use an instance to call the controller how can i retrive the data?
Should i just instance when i want to get the final result?

Comment: @ADyson Routing engine, you mean that i should instantiate a controller from a route?(get,post..)

Comment: @user3783243 didn't think much on the query, so just ignore it :)

Comment: thanks a lot for commenting,I appreciate all of you for showing me my mistakes, to see them and learn

Comment: `i should instantiate a controller from a route`...essentially yes. Normally in MVC architectures, the routing engine processes all requests which come into the application, examines the URL, and from that uses its routing rules to work out which controller and action method needs to be called. e.g. in a relatively commonly-used structure, if the url is `https://yoursite.com/user/printData` then it should work out that it needs to instantiate the user controller and run the printData function. Of course, most systems allow the developer to override the defaults with custom route URLs too.

Comment: Have you spent any time studying existing MVC implementations to see what they do?

Comment: I don't see why using the `implement` keyword would stop you from using dependency injection. PHP interfaces require class to explicitly declare what interface it is implementing.

Comment: @ADyson Okei, I get it now. I used Laravel to make some projects, and this one makes use of route system too, calling the controller and defining the route name (didn't know that the routes play a huge role in the MVC architecture)

Comment: @ADyson I did study some examples of repository pattern however,  didn't found a lot of examples on the controller - view part.

Comment: "on the view side" - PHP itself does not know anything about a "view side", and I don't even see how the given error (that you cannot instantiate an interface) is related to MVC after all

Comment: @NicoHaase Model-View-Controller -> I'am talking about the View, were I have all my html and stuff

Comment: @NicoHaase The constructor of UserController requires a parameter(interface), for that reason I tried to instantiate the class UserController on the view
and giving the interface as a parameter(following the MVC architecture). I know, and i said it, I didn't know that instantiating an object on the view was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a question of how dependency injection is done in PHP.

### Prerequsities

Before anything, you should fix your code by declaring `DataRepository` implements the interface:

```php
class DataRepository implements IData
{
    // ...
}
```

There is no way around it. PHP requires explicit declaration of it.

### Think first...

Then think about the followings:

1. `UserController` depends on `IData`.
2. `DataRepository` is supposed to implements `IData`.
3. Your code should know, when instantiate `UserController`, it needs an `IData` implementation. But there can be more than one of them.
4. How would your code know which `IData` to use for `UserController`?

For (4), you'd need a way to declare that either:

- all classes that want `IData` should have `DataRepository`; or
- **some** of the classes that want `IData`, like `UserController`, should have `DataRepository`.

### Dependency Injection Container

A simple way is to make use of dependency injection container like [PHP-DI](https://php-di.org/). They are flexible in declaring recipes of how an interface dependency should be fulfilled.

Assuming you have "php-di/php-di" installed with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), then you should have this piece of code run in some sort of common php / kernel.

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$db = getDB(); // some way to create the database object
$container = new DI\Container();
$container->set(IData::class, \DI\create(DataRepository::class));
$container->set(DB::class, \DI\value($db));

// ...
```

Should you pass the `$container` variable to your view file, you can simply do this:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

// We create an instance of UserController
$UserData = $container->get(UserController::class);

// Print the data
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($UserData);
echo "</pre>"

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that you do not need to manually create the dependencies of `UserController`. When asked for `UserController`, the container here will search for all the recipes to fulfil all the dependencies required by `UserController`. Thus the view do not need to have knowledge of the implementation details of the controller.

#### More on This

As I mentioned before, you may need to only use `DataRepository` as `IData` for **some** of the controllers. PHP-DI, and other dependency injection container, would have ways for you to specify the recipe to create `DataRepository` to do that.

For PHP-DI, you should read documentation for that, or for other more advanced usages.

### Common MVC frameworks in PHP

I guess a more common MVC design would probably have the controller call for the view. And have controller instantiation (using container) as the implementation details:

Routing:

```php
// Pseudo-code only
// But all MVC framework has its own router / routing code like this

// some container initialization
$container = dummyGetContainer();

// router will probably need container
$router = new MyRouter($container);

// register the handler of GET request to "/userData" 
$router->get('/userData', 'UserController::viewData');

// actually execute the routing
// internally will do:
// 1. find the handler of the request method and path
// 2. instantiate the controller with dependencies.
// 3. execute the handler against the request.
$router->route(dummyGetRequestFromEnvironment());
```

Controller:

```php
class UserController{
    public $Idata;

    // Passing the interface IData to the constructor
    function __construct(IData $Idata) {
        $this->Idata = $Idata;
    }

    function viewData($request) {
        $userData = $this->getData();
        include __DIR__ . '/../views/userDataView.php';
    }

    // Function to search the user and return an array with the data
    function getData(){
        $Mdata = new User();
        $Mdata->id = 5;
        $Mdata->name = "Carl";
        $Mdata->age = 39;

        $result = $this->Idata->search($Mdata);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

View:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php print_r($userData); ?>
</pre>
```

This design is even better because view should not be required to know anything about the controller. It should simply represent the data it is given.

Comment: I never heard of PHP-DI, I will check it and start using routes. Thanks for providing a well explained example

Comment: The router code I wrote here is pseudo-code only. You'll need to write it or find implementation of it. MVC frameworks like Laravel and Symfony all have their own way to specify routes. And they both have their own dependency inject container implementation.